# Issue in Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, ieee-style, ieeeconf

While writing the references for my IEEE conference paper. I facing the following issue. I have posted the image, it can be viewed that the year part is mentioned at the end of first reference whereas its somewhere in between for the second image.
[image: Correct]

[image: Wrong]

Following are the bibtex format for respective papers:

```
@article{Sesen2013,
    author  = {Sesen, M.B. and Nicholson, A.E. and Banares-Alcantara, R. and Kadir, T. and Brady, M.},
    title = {{Bayesian} networks for clinical decision support in lung cancer care},
    journal = {PloS one},
    volume = {8},
    pages = {1--13},
    year = {2013},
}
```

and for second image

```
@inproceedings{Zhang2007,
    author = {Zhang, R. and Bivens, A.},
    title = {Comparing the Use of {Bayesian} Networks and Neural Networks in Response Time Modeling for Service-oriented Systems},
    booktitle = {Proc. of Workshop on Service-oriented Computing Performance: Aspects, Issues, and Approaches (SOCP)},
    pages = {67--74},
    year = {2007},
}
```

Where I am going wrong. I assume that writing attribute 'year' at the end of bibtex will cause it to be printed at the end.

Comment: You're not going wrong or doing anything incorrectly. The two entries have different types: `@article` and `@inproceedings`, respectively. Note that whereas the two entries have four field names in common (`author`, `title`, `year`, and `pages`), they also have field names that aren't shared . For sure, the ordering of the fields has *no influence* on the formatting.

Comment: the order of the fields in the bib field has no effect on the output. the bibliography style you are using is just typesetting the @article and 'inproceedings types as you show.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the problem appears to be caused by have\ing different publication types.